# How can I select a column within a dictionary value with nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover, nhibernate-criteria

I have structure similar to this:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, EntityLocale> Locales { get; set; }
}
public class EntityLocale
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Locales)
                .AsMap<string>("Locale")
                .Component(
                c => {
                         c.Map(x => x.Name);
                     }
                );
    }
}
```

And I want to recieve all names of product locales with a "en" key. With linq it will be:

```
var names = Session.QueryOver<Product>().List().Select(x => x.Locales["en"].Name).ToList();
```

How do I achieve this with nhibernate? (I don't care if it's QueryOver or Criteria api, I just don't want to select everything).

**Update**

I came up with the following ugly hack (which I'm not satisfied with, I don't want any sql in my code):

```
var names = Session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT Name FROM ProductLocales WHERE Locale = 'en'").List<string>()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these cases, NHibernate has very nice solution: [18.1. NHibernate filters](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-filters). At the end, we will select `Product` and apply *filter* on the dictionary... therefore having only `SingleOrDefault()` item in the `Locales`.

Definiton of the Filter

```
public class CulturFilter : FilterDefinition
{
  public CulturFilter()
  {
    WithName("CulturFilter")
        .AddParameter("culture",NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.String);
  }
}
```

and apply it

```
HasMany(x => x.Locales)
  .AsMap<string>("Locale")
  ... 
  .ApplyFilter<CulturFilter>("Locale = :culture"))
;
```

From that moment, whenever you enable the filter in the session (even with some AOP filter), you can be sure that the `IDictionary` contains exactly one (or none) element..

```
session.EnableFilter("CultureFilter")
    .SetParameter("culture", "en");

// applied every time
var criteria = session.CreateCritieria...
var query = session.QueryOver....
```

There is similar posts with some more links if needed https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109300/1679310

#### EDIT: Restricting the column "Locale" directly, getting the list of Names

Other approach (keeping the current solution almost the same) which could be used (and I know about) is to extend the LocalEntity mapping

```
public class EntityLocale
{
    public virtual string CultureName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
public class EntityMap : ClassMap<Entity>
{
    public EntityMap()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.Locales)
            .AsMap<string>("Locale")
            .Component(
            c => {
                c.Map(x => x.CultureName).Formula("Locale").Not.Insert().Not.Update();
                c.Map(x => x.Name);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Having this, we can get the list of all "en" Names like this:

```
var criteria = 
    session.QueryOver<Entity>()
    .JoinQueryOver<IDictionary<string, EntityLocale>>(c => c.Locales)
    .UnderlyingCriteria;

var list = criteria
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CultureName", "en"))
    .SetProjection(Projections.SqlProjection("Name"
        , new string[] { "name" }
        , new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.String }))
    .List()
    .Cast<string>()
    .ToList<String>();
```

Now we have a list containing all the `Names` from EntityLocale filtered by "en" culture

Comment: That's a great start. Can you add just a bit more information on how to access the dictionary (JoinQueryOver?) and how to select just 1 column ( **.Select(x => x.Locales["en"].Name).ToList();** in linq )

Comment: I really rather not changing the dictionary to a list.. Are you sure there's no alternative?

Comment: Not sure... but... what we can do... is to extend the `EntityLocale` object anyway! so it can also have a property `local` (containg "en", "cs") marked as readonly (NHibernate will manage that column as a key of dictionary, and allow us to use it for select and where restricting ... another trick I like to use.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you try and elaborate on how to map the new readonly property? and how do I query over it if the Locale object doesn't know the entity that contains him? (in the C# object, it has an EntityId column in the database). Maybe I should surrender and turn to hql?

Comment: I've updated my answer, with the answer you wanted... sorry for taking you into different dicrections (filter). I am using it and think, that it is amazing feature. But now you have what you needed ;)